# Lock screen audio

Tags: audio, screen-lock

I'd like to allow audio to keep working when the screen lock is activated. I.e. the computer should not sleep, really, but I want the security of automatic locking.

I'm on OSX 10.8.5, if it matters.

Answer (score -1):

This should work: go to System Preferences > Mission Control > Hot Corners… (button on the lower left). On one of the drop down menus (I recommend the lower left), select Put Display to Sleep. To lock the screen you now just have to place the mouse in the corner you designated, but the time it takes for the lock to engage is determined in the Security and Privacy panel of System Preferences > General. Now when your screen is locked music/audio will continue to play (including Airplay music streaming), also downloads will continue, etc., but a password will be required to turn your screen back on.

Comment: Using hot corners is not automatic locking. Also AFAIK this will not stop the computer from going to sleep

Comment: @markhunte Exactly. If only one could get the screensaver to kick in after a few minutes...

Comment: Waitasec...there's a dropdown for that...

Comment: @JonasN, You can. From the Screen Saver system preferences. But if you do not want computer sleep then you would put it to Never in the Energy system preferences

Comment: This is odd -- I have both screen saver and Display sleep set at one minute, but despite not touching the mouse, neither seems to activate. Huh.

Comment: Works fine for me on 10.9.1— try turning your screensaver off. It does seem to take longer than 1 minute though to sleep and lock?

Comment: Yes, it seems to take longer than one minute even with screen saver at "1 minute". Confusing when you just want to test it to gain confidence in auto-locking actually locking. Anyway, it now works well, it seems all you have to do is avoid sleeping and use screen saver. Thanks for the effort.